# Zip a folder in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am busy creating a zip file from a folder in flash. So far i have the following.

```
public function writeFolderToZip():void {
            var byteLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            byteLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            byteLoader.addEventListener (flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, onBytesLoaded);
            var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("//Users/Thibaut/Desktop/vincent_test.indd");
            byteLoader.load (fileRequest);  
        }

        public function onBytesLoaded(event:flash.events.Event):void {
            var saveZip : Function = function(zip : FZip) : void {
                var out : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                zip.serialize(out);

                saveRef.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, 
                 function(e : flash.events.Event) : void {
                    trace("done");
                });

                var fs : FileStream = new FileStream;
                var targetFile : File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(zipName);
                fs.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE);
                fs.writeBytes(out);
                fs.close();
            };
                var zip : FZip = new FZip();
                zip.addFile("vincent_test.indd", event.target.data);
                saveZip(zip);
        }
```

This selects a file with the urlLoader, zips it and puts it on my desktop as a zip. This is working very well but how can i select a folder instead of a file? I want to select a folder, with its subfolders and content and save it on my desktop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method `flash.filesystem.File.browseForDirectory()`

See: [Adobe AS3 reference flash.filesystem.File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForDirectory%28%29)